# MongDB find document by top-level property and nested array key, and return part of the matched document

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB. I have the following JSON documents in a MongoDB collection.

```
{
    name: "Alice",
    orders: {
        1: {
            items: [11,22,33,…],
            delivery: [
                {
                    from: area1
                    to: area2
                },
                {
                    from: area2
                    to: area3
                },
                ⋮
            ],
            areas: {
                area1: {
                   address: "area1 address"
                   contacts: [1,2,3,…] 
                },
                area2: {
                    address: "area2 address"
                    contacts: [4,2,8,…] 
                },
                ⋮
            }
        }            
        2: { … },
        3: { … },
        4: { … },
        5: { … }
        ⋮
    }
​}
​⋮
```

I want to search documents with a certain `name` and a specific order by they **key** in `orders` and return a subpart of the matched document containing the matched order.

For example, for the name Alice and order 1, i want to retrieve:

```
{
    name: "Alice",
    orders: {
        1: {
            items: [11,22,33,…],
            delivery: [
                {
                    from: area1
                    to: area2
                },
                {
                    from: area2
                    to: area3
                },
                ⋮
            ],
            areas: {
                area1: {
                   address: "area1 address"
                   contacts: [1,2,3,…] 
                },
                area2: {
                    address: "area2 address"
                    contacts: [4,2,8,…] 
                },
                ⋮
            }
        }
    }
​}
```

I am using PyMongo, how do i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can retrieve a full record this way: `db.find_one({'name': 'Alice'})` but cannot get the order by Key and don't know how to exclude other records not matching the Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with PyMongo, but AFAIK you would filter your result by passing a second argument to `find_one` as the `projection`, "a list of field names that should be returned in the result set or a dict specifying the fields to include or exclude" [see the docs on `find`, which also apply to `find_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find). In the projection, you can "turn on/off" individual fields to return by passing `0` or `1` as value, so I'd try something like this:

```py
db.find_one({'name': 'Alice'}, 
            {'orders': {1: 1}}
            )
```

Comment: Thank you @fsimonjetz. This works, however, it only returns me the `order` JSON which is a subdocument, and not the main document properties. For example, it does not return the `name` in JSON. I want to get the main document with the searched `order`. The output of your suggestion is `{"orders":{"2":{…}}}`, what I want is `{"name":"Alice","orders":{'2':{…}}}`, or even better if I can get `{"name":"Alice","orders":{…}}}`

Comment: It only returns the `order` JSON because that's what is defined in the second argument. If you need the name, too, change `{'orders':{1: 1}}` in the function call to `{'name':1, 'orders': {1: 1}}` – but if you need the whole entry, `db.find_one({'name': 'Alice'})` should do, no?

Comment: Or is the problem to extract the data from the entries once you retrieved them? Since the entries are JSON, I'd assume you can get the subelements via indexing, e.g, `match = db.find_one({'name': 'Alice'}); print(match['orders'][1])` – does that work?

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you.